# Determining correction terms for an equivalent form to the relativistic Schrödinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, schroedinger-equation

I am reading the book **Stochastic Processes in Quantum Physics** by Masao Nagasawa and I am having a bit of trouble getting my head around the following result. I would much appreciate any help. The thing is that Theorem 7.2.1 says that if $\psi(x,t)=\exp(R(x,t)+iS(x,t))$, where $R$ and $S$ are real valued, satisfies the relativistic Schrödinger equation
$$i\partial_t \psi=\left(\sqrt{-c^2\Delta+m^2c^4 }-mc^2\right)\psi$$
then $\phi_{\pm}(x,t)$ defined as $\phi_{\pm}(x,t)=\exp(R(x,t)\pm S(x,t))$ satisfy
$$\pm\partial_t \phi_{\pm}-v(x,t)\phi_{\pm}=\left(\sqrt{-c^2\Delta+m^2c^4 +c\{\nabla, \textbf{B}(x,t)\}+v(x)^2}-mc^2\right)\phi_{\pm}$$
where ${v}(t, x)$ and $\textbf{B}(t, x)$ are determined by the equations
$$
c\textbf{B}  \cdot \nabla R-v \frac{\partial R}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial^{2} S}{\partial t^{2}}+2 \frac{\partial R}{\partial t} \frac{\partial S}{\partial t}=0
\tag{1}
$$
$$
c\textbf{B}\cdot \nabla S-v\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}-mc^2\right)+c^{2} \Delta R+c^{2} (\nabla R)^{2}+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial t}\right)^{2}=0
\tag{2}
$$
under the gauge condition
$$
c\nabla \cdot \textbf{B}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}
$$

What I don't understand is the following claim: on page 239 it says that one can determine the correction terms $\textbf{B} (t, x)$ and $v(t, x)$ of vector and scalar potentials using equations (1) and (2).  That is what don't comprehend, I can't see how one could compute $\textbf{B}$ and $v$ from these equations. Maybe I could add that I am ultimately interested in taking the non-relativistic limit $c\to+\infty $, so what would be ideal would be to have a closed expression for the correction terms $\textbf{B}$ and $v$.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bit too long of a response for a comment but I hope it can help:

In the limit $c \to \infty$, your equations reduce to

$$
\textbf{B}  \cdot \nabla R=0
\tag{1}
$$
$$
mv+ \Delta R+ (\nabla R)^{2}=0
\tag{2}
$$
with the non-relativistic gauge condition $ \nabla \cdot {\bf B} = 0$. So we can generally take ${\bf B}=\nabla \times A$ for some vector potential $A$. However, I notice that this is a strictly one dimensional problem, so we have ${\bf B}=k + f(t)$, a constant plus some function in time.
Additionally, $R$ is one dimensional, so we can re-write these equations as
$$
(k+f(t)) \cdot R'(x) = 0
\tag{1*}
$$
$$
mv+R''(x)+(R'(x))^2=0
\tag{2*}
$$
it looks like equation 1 can simplify to $R(x)=n$, another constant.
All told, this constant solution seems quite mundane, so hopefully someone can shed some further light on this problem.

Comment: Hi Jacob, thank you very much for your answer. The non-relativistic limit of equations (1) and (2) that you have are exactly what I would have expected. However, I can't help but notice that $R$, $S$, and $v$ could depend on $c$ ($R$ and $S$ most likely do, as a solution to the relativistic Schrödinger equation) so I am not sure how one can argue that this limit is the right one?